# Azure LogicApp string to datetime

Tags: azure-logic-apps

How to convert string with format 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss' to datetime in Azure LogicApp workflow?
Possible only with Azure Functions which realize DateTime.ParseExact()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String parsing aside, the only way to run custom code in a Logic App is with an Azure Function.

So, the answer to your question is **YES, use an Azure Function**.

Answer (score 2):

You can split and reverse. example: `formatDateTime(concat(datestring, '/')[2], '-', split(datestring, '/')[1], '-', split(datestring, '/')[0]), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')`

It take `12/06/2018` which is seen as invalid and will basically make it `06/12/2018` then in my case we needed `2018-06-12`. issue with Azure is it only allows `mm-dd-yyyy` in the beginning. So you gotta split it and reverse you know.

Comment: Just needed to add a missing split after the concat like so- formatDateTime(concat(split(datestring, '/')[2], '-', split(datestring, '/')[1], '-', split(datestring, '/')[0]), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')

Answer (score 1):

For the record, currently, you are able to run snippets of javascript to do many different tasks, including converting strings to dates.

In this case, you would do something like this

```
let dateStr = '2011-04-11T10:20:30Z'
new Date(dateStr)
```

You can send your date str as input to the inline code action, and return as output your converted date

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code#:%7E:text=Add%20inline%20code.%20If%20you%20haven%27t%20already%2C%20in,pointer%20over%20the%20arrow%20that%20connects%20those%20steps.)